# How to create a button with rounded corners and set any colour programatically at run time

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-drawable

I am trying to create a widget `button` with rounded corners which I can also change to ANY colour I want. I currently use an xml layout file to create the rounded corners. The problem is when I change the colour the `button` returns to its rectangular shape. I would like for it to maintain at least its rounded corners.

I can't find a solution for this but any ideas gratefully received. It may not be possible but thought I'd ask. The main point is that I am trying to do this with remote views as part of a widget NOT in an activity which is easy to do.

Happy to consider any options...

Thank you

```
RemoteViews views;
views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.mycustomlayout);
views.setInt(R.id.widgetbutton,"setBackgroundColor", Color.parseColor(widgethexcolor));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout resource file in drawable folder and call that as 
**android:background="@drawable/shape.xml"** inside properties of button.

*Instead of Gradient you can use Solid also*

Code for shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<corners
    android:radius="20dp"
    />

<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:centerX="35%"
    android:centerColor="#00d6a3"
    android:startColor="#9e9c97"
    android:endColor="#ffffff"
    android:type="linear"
    />
<size
    android:height="45dp"
    android:width="250dp"
    />
</shape>
```

Comment: Sorry guys - but this wont work.  I obviously wasn't clear. The colour needs to be set programmatically and could literally be anything. I can't create XML files for every possible colour.

Comment: If you are still facing the problem, please state your problem clearly so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this and follow the steps :
 1. Create a shape file as per your need
 2. Set shape file as background of your widget
 3. From your `.java` file change color as per requirements.

**bg_button_round_corners.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#CBCBCB"/>   <!-- you can use any color you want-->
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

**Layout File:**

```
   <Button
      android:id="@+id/customButton"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="56dp"
      android:textSize="12sp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:background="@drawable/bg_button_round_corners"/>
```

**Activity File:**

```
   customButton= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.customButton);
   int color = Color.parseColor("#00FFFF");
   ((GradientDrawable)circleColor.getBackground()).setColor(color);
```

Answer (score -1):

First create a resource file inside drawable folder, named for example : bg_white_rounded.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/space5"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</shape>
```

then at your button layout add :

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded.xml"
```

PS: change the wanted dimension of the space radius.

Comment: Sorry guys - but this wont work.  I obviously wasn't clear. The colour needs to be set programmatically and could literally be anything. I can't create XML files for every possible colour.

Comment: You have to state more clearly what you are looking for then. Color* and first you can't create XML files for colors, you have to declare them as colors. Secondly if it's a static you have to use a dedicated drawable file for that with the given color*. If you are gettin it from parsing, then you have to write more clearly what you are looking for ;)